# jquery unable to add child list <ul> tags to appended <p> tag

Tags: jquery

I try to insert some child tag to a`<div>` tag like that :

```
$('#div1')
.append('<p style="float:left;width:82%;">blablablalb <ul><li>llist item</li><li>another list item</li></ul></p>');

<div id="div1"></div>
```

I get this result :

```
<div id="div1">
   <p style="float:left;width:82%;">
       blablablalb 
   </p>
   <ul>
      <li>llist item</li>
      <li>another list item</li>
   </ul>
   <p></p>
</div>
```

But I would like the code to be hierarchised as written in the .append argument. Ie. the list should be inside the `<p>` element and not after.

Is there a way to do that ?

http://jsfiddle.net/jPEWW/

Comment: You cannot put an `ul` within `p` tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually this is not related to jQuery. You cannot use an `ul` element within a `p` element, most of the browsers close the `p` element when they see `ul` element has been used.